# I've proved everything about the ideal correspondence easily except $\pi ^{-1} \pi (\frak{a}) = \frak{a}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

The correspondence theorem to which I refer is the bijection between ideals of a commutative ring with $1$, $A$, and ideals of $A/\frak{b}$.  I can prove easily most parts that imply the bijection except for this last bit: $\pi^{-1} \pi (\frak{a}) \subset \frak{a}$, where $\pi$ is the natural surjection $A \to A/\frak{a}$.

Attempt: suppose that $\pi^{-1} \pi(\frak{a} ) \supsetneq \frak a$.  Take $x \in$ the difference.  Then $x + \frak{a}$ is a coset disjoint from & not equal to $0 + \frak a$ in the quotient ring.  Also notice that $x = x + 0 \in x + \frak{a} \subset \pi^{-1}\pi(\frak{a}) $.  Composing the first set inequality with $\pi$ then gives us  $\pi(\frak{a}) \supsetneq \pi(\frak{a})$ since $x + \frak{a} \not\subset \frak{a}$. Contradiction.

Is this proof correct?  How can I make this proof better or more elegant?

Comment: is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106294/correspondence-principle-applied-to-ideals-of-a-quotient-ring/1106571#1106571) helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd rephrase your argument (and prove the bijection directly all at once):

$$\begin{align*}
\pi^{-1}(\pi(\mathfrak{a}))&=\pi^{-1}(\{\pi(x):x\in\mathfrak{a}\})\\[0.05in]
&=\pi^{-1}(\{x+\mathfrak{a}:x\in\mathfrak{a}\})\\[0.05in]
&=\pi^{-1}(\{0+\mathfrak{a}\})\\[0.05in]
&=\{y\in A:\pi(y)=0+\mathfrak{a}\}\\[0.05in]
&=\{y\in A: y+\mathfrak{a} = 0+\mathfrak{a}\}\\[0.05in]
&=\{y\in A: y\in\mathfrak{a}\}\\[0.05in]
&=\mathfrak{a}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I don't think that's a rephrasing.  It's a complete rewriting.  And mine used plenty of math-English o__O

Comment: Well, it's ultimately going the same idea - there's basically only one way to do this. The main "modification" I feel I made to what you said was that I removed the unnecessary appeal to proof by contradiction, after that everything else I wrote proceeds naturally (IMHO).